# Controller method: Contact form should render different page depending on where the form is used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

I have a contact form on a special page dedicated to this form. The dedicated controller includes:

```
def new
  @message = Message.new
end

def create
  @message = Message.new(message_params)
  if @message.valid?
    MessageMailer.new_message(@message).deliver_now
    flash[:success] = "Thank you!"
    redirect_to contact_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Now I would also like to include this form at the bottom of my home page. I have added the html to the view and added to the home page its controller:

```
  def home
    @message = Message.new
  end
```

The form now also works on the home page. But here is the problem: If I submit the form on the homepage it redirects to the special contact page (because of `redirect_to contact_path`). And also if there's an error, it goes to the special contact page (because of `render 'new'`).

*What would be the most efficient way to remedy this, so that it renders the form on the home page (which is all the way at the bottom) if the form there is used?* When the form on de special contact page is used, it should of course still render that page. The only solution I see is write seperate controller methods but that feels like that makes it more complex then it needs to be. Or can I perhaps somehow use `current_page?` method?

---

**Update:** I tried `render current_page?(contact_path) ? 'new' : 'controllername/home'` but this generated the error message: `undefined method 'current_page?'`.

As requested, the form on the home page:

```
<%= form_for @message, url: contact_path do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: 'Name' %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, placeholder: 'Email' %>
  <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: 'Your message…' %>
  <%= f.submit "Post message" %>
<% end %>
```

The form on the seperate page:

```
<%= form_for @message, url: contact_path do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: 'Name', class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, placeholder: 'Email', class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :content %>
  <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: 'Your message…', class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.submit "Send", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you please post your form?

Comment: I added the form code to the OP

Comment: Are you asking that after the submit button is pressed, form should reside on home page again if it was submitted form home page, and it should reside on special contact page if it was submitted from there?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. And I'm basically asking how to do that most efficiently, so without writing completely seperate controller methods. Perhaps use something like `current_page?` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something called `action_name` in Rails 4. `action_name` gives you the name of the action your view got fired from. Now you can send this property to the method `create` through a hidden field like following:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "action_name", action_name %>
```

This line of code will send `params[:action_name]` into the `create` method. And then, there in `create` method you check where the request came from, and take the appropriate action.